# Add event and read event simultaneosly google calendar API android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, calendar, google-calendar-api

i'm trying to make an app that can write google calendar event from user input and also read list of events from my google calendar. I have tried to look for many example but most of them only show very basic example.

I'm using alertdialog to get input from user and wanted to send the data to AsyncTask. I think where i'm wrong is when calling the `createEvent()` in `mActivity.updateResultsText1(createEvent())`

Here is my calendar_activity code.

```
public class CalendarActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

private ListView listevent;
private Button addeventbtn;
private Button deleteeventbtn;
public String nama, tanggal, mulai, beres;

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> eventlist =new ArrayList<String>();

com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;
GoogleAccountCredential credential;
private TextView mStatusText;

final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    listevent=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.kalenderlist);
    addeventbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addeventbutton);
    addeventbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteeventbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteevent);
    deleteeventbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eventlist);

    mStatusText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statustext);

    mStatusText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    mStatusText.setText("Retrieving data...");

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android")
            .build();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.addeventbutton) {

        AlertDialog.Builder addeventdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalendarActivity.this);
        View mViewaddevent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_addevent,null);
        final EditText namaevent=(EditText)mViewaddevent.findViewById(eventname);
        final EditText tanggalevent=(EditText)mViewaddevent.findViewById(eventdate);
        final EditText mulaievent=(EditText)mViewaddevent.findViewById(R.id.eventtimestart);
        final EditText beresevent=(EditText)mViewaddevent.findViewById(R.id.eventtimeend);


        addeventdialog.setView(mViewaddevent);
        final AlertDialog dialog = addeventdialog.create();
        dialog.show();

        Button addbutton=(Button)mViewaddevent.findViewById(R.id.eventsavebutton);
        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!namaevent.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!tanggalevent.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!mulaievent.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!beresevent.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    nama = namaevent.getText().toString();
                    tanggal = tanggalevent.getText().toString();
                    mulai = mulaievent.getText().toString();
                    beres = beresevent.getText().toString();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this,"Masukan tidak lengkap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        Button cancelbtn=(Button)mViewaddevent.findViewById(R.id.eventcancelbutton);
        cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
    if (v.getId()==R.id.deleteevent) {

    }
}

public void updateResultsText(final List<String> dataStrings) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (dataStrings == null) {
                mStatusText.setText("Error retrieving data!");
            } else if (dataStrings.size() == 0) {
                mStatusText.setText("No data found.");
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("Data retrieved using" +
                        " the Google Calendar API:");
                eventlist.addAll(dataStrings);
                listevent.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    });
}

public void updateResultsText1(final String dataStrings1) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (dataStrings1 == null) {
                mStatusText.setText("Error retrieving data!");
            } else if (dataStrings1 == "") {
                mStatusText.setText("No data found.");
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("Data retrieved using" +
                        " the Google Calendar API:");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my AsyncTask Code.

```
public class ApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private CalendarActivity mActivity;

ApiAsyncTask(CalendarActivity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        mActivity.clearResultsText();
        mActivity.updateResultsText(getDataFromApi());
        mActivity.updateResultsText1(createEvent());

    } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
        mActivity.showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode());

    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(
                userRecoverableException.getIntent(),
                CalendarActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        mActivity.updateStatus("The following error occurred: " +
                e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
    // List the next 20 events from the primary calendar.
    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Events events = mActivity.mService.events().list("primary")
            .setMaxResults(20)
            .setTimeMin(now)
            .setOrderBy("startTime")
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .execute();
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();

    for (Event event : items) {
        DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
        if (start == null) {
            // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
            // the start date.
            start = event.getStart().getDate();
        }
        eventStrings.add(
                String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
    }
    return eventStrings;
}

private String createEvent() throws IOException {

    Event event2 = new Event()
            .setSummary(mActivity.nama);

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(mActivity.tanggal+"T"+mActivity.mulai+":00+07:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Jakarta");
    event2.setStart(start);

    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(mActivity.tanggal+"T"+mActivity.beres+":00+07:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Jakarta");
    event2.setEnd(end);

    String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
    event2.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

    String calendarId = "primary";
    try {
        event2 =  mActivity.mService.events().insert(calendarId, event2).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event2.getHtmlLink());
    Log.e("Event", "created : " + event2.getHtmlLink());
    String eventStrings = "created : " + event2.getHtmlLink();
    return eventStrings;
}
```

Here is what my app looks like [Calendar activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxY14.jpg) and [Addevent alertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVth.jpg). I also have another problem. The Listview to put event list from reading Google Calendar event only shows 1 event. If i use textview instead of Listview, and joining all event into one string, 20 events can be showed.

Thanks for reading my question and go through my bad code. Hopefully you can answer them.